# Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'

Tags: java, flutter, dart, debugging, keystore

I have got this problem. the  emulator is open when ı start debugging ı came across this problem.
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\mehme.android\debug.keystore.lock

Comment: Are you logged in as an admin? Do you have full acess? Do you have any antivirus program running? (Avast?)

Comment: this is the first time ı came across this. I have full access on vs code .I am only using windows defender as antivirus.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and what **solved it was deleting the file debug.keystore.lock**,

My issue started when I created an SSH key with the command keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore c:\Users.....

It created the debug.keystore and the debug.keystore.lock, apparently the lock was not giving permission to run the app.

Comment: yes ı did same thing and it worked .thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved with these steps:

I am a Windows User so these steps applying in Windows.

Adding English Language for windows display from Control Panel.
Change windows region format to US from Control Panel.
Open SDK Update Sites tab in SDK Manager and see if there is 15 URLs for updates Otherwise relook to Windows Region Format from windows Control Panel.
Update Android SDK Build-Tools to last stable version from SDK Manager.
Update Android Emulator from SDK Manager.
Update Android SDK Platform-Tools to last stable version from SDK Manager.

Clear caches from "C:\Users\USER_NAME.gradle\caches".
Clear caches from "C:\Users\USER_NAME.android\cache".

Finally Run the app on that new emulator.